# Changing the select list affects the records selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query as follows...

```
select *
from (select COL1, COL2, COL3,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2,COL3 ORDER BY COL2,COL3) AS rn
     from TABLE
    ) t
where rn = 1
```

Which returns expected results. When I modify the outer select to explicitly ask for the columns without the row number column thus...

```
select COL1, COL2, COL3 from
from (select COL1, COL2, COL3,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL2, COL3 ORDER BY COL2, COL3) AS rn from TABLE
     ) t
where rn = 1
```

I get different results.  In fact the combinations of values in the returned COL1,COL2 and COL3 columns do not actually exist in any row in the database.

Have I gone mad, found a bug or more likely, do I misunderstand how this should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included `col1` in either the `partition by` or the `order by`.  So, my guess is that you have multiple rows where `col2` and `col3` have the same value (and different values in `col1`).

In SQL, sorting is not stable -- that is, rows with the same same key can appear in any order.  This is even true when you run the same query twice.  And, that is what you are witnessing; simply that the sort is not stable.

Unstable sorts make *perfect* sense in SQL.  Tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "natural" ordering to use when keys have the same value.

If you want a stable sort, include an additional column in the `order by`; for instance, if you included `col1` then you would get the same results each time you run the query.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Your answer not only explains what I am seeing, but also helps me to realise that my contention that none of the rows returned really existed is a lie.

Comment: i get what you mean. so the partition by col2,col3 order by should be col1 right? i just tried this myself and found out it just ordered by col1 no matter how many time i tried. Is there some default order in database?

Comment: @Raffaello.D.Huke . . . There are cases where SQL Server might process things in a particular order (such as if `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` were in an index).  But there are no guarantees.